# SELECT random 10% of rows for each category on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table of products sold.

| row_id | customer | product | date_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | customer_1 | thingamajig | 01.01.2023 |
| 2 | customer_12 | whosi-whatsi | 03.01.2023 |
| 3 | customer_1 | watchamacallit | 04.01.2023 |
| 4 | customer_4 | whosi-whatsi | 06.01.2023 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

There is always one row per one item.

Let's say `customer_1` ordered 100 items total. `customer_2` ordered 50 items total. `customer_3` ordered 17 items total. **How do you select random 10% of rows for each customer?** The fraction of rows selected should be rounded up (for example 12 rows total results in 2 selected). That means every customer that bought at least one item should appear in the resulting table. In this case the resulting table for `customer_1`, `customer_2` and `customer_3` would have 10 + 5 + 2 = 17 rows.

My initial approach would be to create a temp table, calculate desired row counts for each customer and then loop through the temp table and select rows for each customer. Then insert them to another table and select from that one:

```sql
drop table if exists #row_counts

select
    customer
    ceiling(convert(decimal(10, 2), count(product)) / 10) as row_count
into #row_counts
from products_sold
group by customer

-- then use cursor to loop over #row_counts and insert into the final table
-- for randomness an 'order by newid()' will be used
```

But this just doesn't feel like the right solution...

Comment: A cursor is not a wise solution if a set-oriented option exists, which in almost all cases it does, and performance is a factor. Some suitable sample data for your expected results would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to know total count and a row count of what you want.
Something like this can perhaps be of service:

EDITED due to it not being randomized properly:

```sql
select *
from ( 
   select row_number() over(partition by customerid order by  newid()) as sortOrder
   , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY customerID) AS cnt
   , *
   FROM products
 ) p
-- Now, we want 10% of total count rounded upwards
WHERE sortOrder <= CEILING(cnt * 0.1)
```

Comment: That's curious. A quick [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7B9dR1NG) seems to show that using `order by (select newid())` causes the same results to be returned for every run. Using `order by newid()` returns varying, i.e. "random", results. The actual execution plans differ for the two queries ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O_qN9qnl)), but I'm failing to interpret the difference in a meaningful way.

Comment: VERY interesting @HABO. What's even more interesting is that if you include (SELECT NEWID()) as a separate column, it randomizes it! OP, you need to watch out for this

Comment: It almost looks like a bug

Comment: Using `order by newid()` gets me different result set every time which I find suffiecient for my application. However I'm failing to understand why adding `(select newid())` randomizes it. And how is it different from adding just `newid()` as a column? And is therefore the accepted solution not random 'enough' or at all? Thanks !

Comment: sorry @user15634990, i was a bit unclear. what i meant was that (select newid()) as a separate column generated new GUID value for every row of the select. But it doesn't seem to work inside ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select newid())), there it doesn't randomize the order. This is a bit fishy behaviour to me